# Create a LINQ query

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following table:

[image]

I would like to write a LINQ query that makes the following:

- from last column('Halott adatai') extract the values and split in two
- count the first and the second splitted dates
- the rows (Date) should be unique

Ex:

```
|Date|Count1|Count2|

|1977|1     |0     |

|1974|1     |0     |

|1972|1     |0     |

|1971|2     |0     |

|1999|0     |15    |
```

Edit: I wrote something in SQL, but is not 100% correct:

```
select Elhunyva, Osszes1 as `OsszesHalott`, Osszes2 as `OsszesSZ` from 
(
(select substr(`Halott adatai`,0,instr(`Halott adatai`,'-')) as Elhunyva, Count(*) as Osszes1 from Holtak
group by substr(`Halott adatai`,0,instr(`Halott adatai`,'-'))) A left join
(select substr(`Halott adatai`,instr(`Halott adatai`, '-')+1) as Szuletve, Count(*) as Osszes2 from Holtak
group by substr(`Halott adatai`,instr(`Halott adatai`, '-')+1)) B on B.Szuletve=A.Elhunyva
)
union all
select Elhunyva, Osszes1 as `OsszesHalott`, Osszes2 as `OsszesSzületett` from 
(
(select substr(`Halott adatai`,instr(`Halott adatai`, '-')+1) as Elhunyva, Count(*) as Osszes1 from Holtak
group by substr(`Halott adatai`,instr(`Halott adatai`, '-')+1)) A left join
(select substr(`Halott adatai`,0,instr(`Halott adatai`,'-')) as Szuletve, Count(*) as Osszes2 from Holtak
group by substr(`Halott adatai`,instr(`Halott adatai`, '-')+1)) B on B.Szuletve=A.Elhunyva
) GROUP BY ELHUNYVA ORDER BY ELHUNYVA
```

Comment: Clean up the data before you insert it into the database. In any case, LINQ doesn't query a database by itself nor is it a SQL replacement. You probably want to use it on top of an ORM like Entity Framework. An ORM's job is to map *Objects* to tables, not expose those tables. It's a LOT easier to do that with clean data

Comment: A lot is not clear in your question. How is the SQL *not 100% correct*? Which database provider is this? Where are you in this process of writing LINQ? Did you already map the table to a class model using Entity Framework? If so, which version?

Comment: Which database?

Comment: the database that I'm using is SQLite. Right now I'm testing the SQL query in SQLite with the idea to change this SQL query to LINQ query.  In the viewmodel I get all the data from the table, so now I just only need to filter the data/create a Linq query. ( I'm working in Xamarin Master-detail, in C#)

Comment: *only need to (...) create a Linq query*. Do you have any idea which choices you have to make before the first LINQ statement can be written? We can't make these decisions. You tagged linq-to-entities. That's a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it is close to your requirements. If you need exact output that you have mentioned with `Count1` and `Count2` this query has to be changed.

```cs
var subQuery = 
    from h in ctx.Holtak
    select new
    {
        p.HalottAdatai,
        Idx = p.HalottAdatai.IndexOf("a")
    };

var part1 =
    from q in subQuery
    select new
    {
        Elhunyva = q.HalottAdatai.Substring(0, q.Idx)
    };

var part2 =
    from q in subQuery
    select new
    {
        Elhunyva = q.HalottAdatai.Substring(q.Idx + 1, q.ProductName.Length - q.Idx)
    };

var concated = part1.Concat(part2);

var grouped = from q in concated
    group q by q.Elhunyva into g
    select new 
    {
        Elhunyva = g.Key, 
        Count = g.Count()
    };

var result = grouped.ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 3  `GroupBy()` and a `Concat()`.

```
public class Row
{
    public int ID;
    public int SID;
    public string LastCol;
}
public class ResultRow
{
    public string Date;
    public int Count1;
    public int Count2;
}

#region Data preparing
string[] dtRanges =
{
    "1977-1999",
    "1974-1999",
    "1972-1999",
    "1971-1999",
    "1971-1999",
    "1961-1999",
    "1960-1999",
    "1957-1999",
    "1953-1999",
    "1950-1999",
    "1950-1999",
    "1946-1999",
    "1943-1999",
    "1940-1999",
    "1939-1999",
    "1920-1920" // To see what's going to happen whean date in both columns |1920|1|1|
};

List<Row> table = dtRanges
    .Select(x => new Row { LastCol = x })
    .ToList();
#endregion

var part1 = table.GroupBy(
    key => key.LastCol.Split('-').First(), 
    val => val,
    (key, val) => new ResultRow
    {
        Date = key,
        Count1 = val.Count()
    });

var part2 = table.GroupBy(
    key => key.LastCol.Split('-').Last(), 
    val => val,
    (key, val) => new ResultRow
    {
        Date = key,
        Count2 = val.Count()
    });

var result = part1
    .Concat(part2)
    .GroupBy(
        key => key.Date,
        val => val,
        (key, val) => new ResultRow
        {
            Date = key,
            Count1 = val.Sum(x => x.Count1),
            Count2 = val.Sum(x => x.Count2),
        }).ToList();
```

[image]